# inputmask regex edit doesn't work

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-inputmask

I tried to use custom regex for [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask)  plugin, it works well on the first time I type something in the input field, however when I wanted to edit the input field, the plugin's behavior becomes slightly unpredictable. For example 12:20pm is valid input for the following regex but if I tried to edit the input by moving the cursor to : position and delete :20 and then if I tried to enter any valid characters (ex change 12:20pm to 12:30pm), the plugin doesn't let me type those character.

This is how I initialized the plugin

```
//Let user enter HH:mm format or hh:mm meridian or HH:mm meridian format
// Don't worry about semantics, validator will take care of it   
$(".time").inputmask(
    "Regex",
        regex: "^((1|0)?[0-9]|2[0-4])(:[0-5][0-9])?([APap][Mm])?$"
    }
);
```

Comment: Does it mean you want the regex to also validate `23:55am`? As if it were valid? Please check [my attempt](https://regex101.com/r/tV9jU3/2), is it what you need?

Comment: I want (or let) the regex to accept that as valid string, in this case, I don't want the inputmask have to worry about semantic yet and my problem is when user want to edit a portion of string, the inputmask plugin doesn't let the user edit it. Am I using the plugin wrongly?

Comment: No idea if you are using it properly or improperly, but your regex does not allow all partial matches, that is why I tried adding this flexibility.